# Make sticky element with overflow hidden expand

Tags: html, css

How can I make a sticky element, with overflow hidden, expand to fill parent element that has scroll on overflow?

A minor example:

```css
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #844;
}
.stick {
  position: sticky;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #484;
  top: 0;
}
.text {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="stick">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 10 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40</div>
  <pre class="text">Hello and good bye to the sticky scroll once the wrap area scrolls past the initial width
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
</pre>
</div>
```

Here the green line is sticky, but it does not fill the width of the scroll element, which is what I'm trying to achieve. The effect is visible once one start scrolling. I can solve it by JS, but hoping to do it with CSS.

The sticky element has overflow hidden as it, in real code, contains a wide canvas as a sub element. This element is wider then the content, as in "text" above, and should not be visible beyond the size of "text".

A picture:

[image]

- The Yellow part is sticky to top: Scroll up / down it stays at top.
- The Yellow part scrolls left / right. Follows the blue content left / right.
- The Yellow part does not expand the blue part / viewable content AKA overflow hidden.
- The Yellow part has full width of blue part

So the yellow sticky should:

1. Have same width as blue. Anything beyond this hidden
2. Stay at top of view-port if window scroll up/ down
3. Follow content left / right

---

In the real project I use it in a MDI layout with multiple absolute positioned "windows" having one sticky element on top and left of content area. Much like for example when you have a picture open in GIMP. (The pixel bars). Too complex to post code for it, but here is a small mock-up:

The "window" can be resized by dragging element in bottom-right corner.

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  const spacer = {
    el: null,
    sz: {
      small: [100, 100],
      wide: [1000, 100],
      high: [100, 1000],
      big: [1000, 1000]
    },
    change: function (ev) {
      let z = spacer.sz[ev.target.value];
      spacer.el.style.width = z[0] + 'px';
      spacer.el.style.height = z[1] + 'px';
    },
    init: function () {
      spacer.el = document.querySelector('.content-spacer');
      spacer.el.addEventListener('change', spacer.change);
    }
  };

  const resizer = {
    el: null,
    overlay: null,
    move: function (ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      ev.stopPropagation();
      resizer.el_rz.style.marginTop = (ev.layerY - resizer.pos[0]) + 'px';
      resizer.el_rz.style.marginLeft = (ev.layerX - resizer.pos[1]) + 'px';
    },
    end: function () {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', resizer.move);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', resizer.end);
      resizer.overlay.style.display = 'none';

    },
    start: function (ev) {
      let t = ev.target,
          cs = getComputedStyle(t)
      ;
      ev.preventDefault();
      ev.stopPropagation();
      resizer.el_rz = ev.target;

      resizer.pos = [
        ev.clientX - (parseInt(cs.marginLeft) || 0),
        ev.clientY - (parseInt(cs.marginTop) || 0),
      ];
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', resizer.end);
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', resizer.move);
      resizer.overlay.style.display = 'block';
    },
    init: function () {
      resizer.el = document.getElementById("sizer");
      resizer.overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
      resizer.el.addEventListener('mousedown', resizer.start);
    }
  };
  
  function fill_numbers(el) {
      let i, s = '';
      for (i = 1; i < 500; ++i)
        s += (i % 10) + ' ';
      el.textContent = s;
  }
  
  resizer.init();
  spacer.init();

  fill_numbers(document.querySelector('.top-line-c'));
  fill_numbers(document.querySelector('.left-line-c'));
})();
```

```css
body {
  position            : relative;
  width               : 100vw;
  height              : 100%;
  padding             : 0;
  margin              : 0;
}
#overlay {
  position            : absolute;
  display             : none;
  z-index             : 100;
  height              : 100vh;
  width               : 100vw;
  opacity             : 0.1;
  background          : #333;
  z-index             : 100;
  cursor              : move;
}
.window {
  position            : absolute;
  overflow            : hidden;
  margin-top          : 5px;
  margin-left         : 5px;
  min-width           : 10px;
  min-height          : 10px;
  background          : #988;
  padding             : 0;
}
.sizer {
  position            : relative;
  background          : #8a8;
  bottom              : 0;
  right               : 0;
  width               : 15px;
  height              : 15px;
  margin-top          : 120px;
  margin-left         : 250px;
  cursor              : move;
}
.wrap {
  position            : relative;
  background          : #565;
  width               : 100%;
  height              : 100%;
}
.content-outer {
  overflow            : hidden;
  top                 : 0;
  bottom              : 0;
  right               : 0;
  left                : 0;
  position            : absolute;
  background          : #a77;
  padding             : 0;
}
.corner {
  position            : sticky;
  width               : 25px;
  height              : 25px;
  top                 : 0;
  left                : 0;
  z-index             : 150;
  background          : red;
}
.top-line {
  top                 : 0;
  margin-top          : -25px;
  margin-left         : 25px;
  position            : sticky;
  height              : 25px;
  background          : pink;
  width               : 100%;

  white-space         : nowrap;
  z-index             : 100;
  overflow            : hidden;
}
.left-line {
  position            : sticky;
  max-height          : 100%;
  overflow            : hidden;
  background          : #494;
  width               : 25px;
  left                : 0;
  z-index             : 100;
  text-align          : center;
}
.left-line-c {
  height              : 5000px;
}
.content-inner {
  position            : absolute;
  overflow            : scroll;
  top                 : 25px;
  right               : 0;
  bottom              : 0;
  left                : 0;
}
.content-text {
  position            : absolute;
  top                 : 0;
  left                : 0;
  right               : 0;
  bottom              : 0;
  margin              : 25px ;
}
.content-spacer {
  background: rgb(186,124,13);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(186,124,13,1) 0%, rgba(112,25,58,0.9037815809917717) 53%, rgba(181,0,255,1) 100%);
  margin              : 15px;
  width               : 1000px;
  height              : 100px;
}
ul {
  list-style          : none;
  margin              : 0;
  padding             : 0;
}
.header {
  background          : #000;
  color               : #aaa;
  height              : 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="window">
        <div class="content-outer">
            <div class="header"><span>Header</span></div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <div class="corner">C</div>
                <div class="top-line">
                  <div class="top-line-c"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="left-line">
                  <div class="left-line-c"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="content-text">
                  <div class="content-spacer">
                    <ul>
                      <li><label><input type="radio" name="sp" value="small">small</label></li>
                      <li><label><input type="radio" name="sp" value="wide" checked>wide</label></li>
                      <li><label><input type="radio" name="sp" value="high">high</label></li>
                      <li><label><input type="radio" name="sp" value="big">big</label></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sizer" id="sizer" tabindex="0"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to add left:0 .. sticky doesn't work if you don't provide a top/left/bottom/right

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Yes, and no. I want it to scroll sideways, but not up and down. Added `top: 0` and some extra lines in the in the pre element to make it scroll both ways and be more clear.

Comment: display: inline-block; then on the sticky element

Comment: @TemaniAfif: But then the overflow fit entire content of the sticky element. Overflow is not hidden. In the small example: I want the pre element to set the width of the scrollable element. The sticky element should be same width. Anything beyond that should be hidden.

Comment: it's not clear at all what you want. Either your want it to sitck and follow the scroll (by adding left:0) or you want to it to fill all width (by adding inline-block)

Comment: @TemaniAfif: OK. Say wrapper is fixed with 300 with overflow scroll. Main content has width 500 which gives an overflow of 200. In other words it scrolls 200. The sticky element at top should stay at top 0 but also scroll with content thus it can not be left 0. But it is much wider then the 500 so it can not be inline block, as then it expands to entire width (overflow hidden is ignored).

Answer (score 0):

See if that is what you're needing :

```css
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #844;
}

.stick {
  position: sticky;
  display: table;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #484;
}

.text {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="stick">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 10 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33</div>
  <pre class="text">Hello and good bye to the sticky scroll once the wrap area scrolls past the initial width</pre>
</div>
```

This is going to expand the `child` `<div>` to the total content of the `parent` `<div>`.

Below the same example with the second snippet attached :

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  const spacer = {
    el: null,
    sz: {
      small: [100, 100],
      wide: [1000, 100],
      high: [100, 1000],
      big: [1000, 1000]
    },
    change: function (ev) {
      let z = spacer.sz[ev.target.value];
      spacer.el.style.width = z[0] + 'px';
      spacer.el.style.height = z[1] + 'px';
    },
    init: function () {
      spacer.el = document.querySelector('.content-spacer');
      spacer.el.addEventListener('change', spacer.change);
    }
  };

  const resizer = {
    el: null,
    overlay: null,
    move: function (ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      ev.stopPropagation();
      resizer.el_rz.style.marginTop = (ev.layerY - resizer.pos[0]) + 'px';
      resizer.el_rz.style.marginLeft = (ev.layerX - resizer.pos[1]) + 'px';
    },
    end: function () {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', resizer.move);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', resizer.end);
      resizer.overlay.style.display = 'none';

    },
    start: function (ev) {
      let t = ev.target,
          cs = getComputedStyle(t)
      ;
      ev.preventDefault();
      ev.stopPropagation();
      resizer.el_rz = ev.target;

      resizer.pos = [
        ev.clientX - (parseInt(cs.marginLeft) || 0),
        ev.clientY - (parseInt(cs.marginTop) || 0),
      ];
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', resizer.end);
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', resizer.move);
      resizer.overlay.style.display = 'block';
    },
    init: function () {
      resizer.el = document.getElementById("sizer");
      resizer.overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
      resizer.el.addEventListener('mousedown', resizer.start);
    }
  };
  
  function fill_numbers(el) {
      let i, s = '';
      for (i = 1; i < 500; ++i)
        s += (i % 10) + ' ';
      el.textContent = s;
  }
  
  resizer.init();
  spacer.init();

  fill_numbers(document.querySelector('.top-line-c'));
  fill_numbers(document.querySelector('.left-line-c'));
})();
```

```css
body {
  position            : relative;
  width               : 100vw;
  height              : 100%;
  padding             : 0;
  margin              : 0;
}
#overlay {
  position            : absolute;
  display             : none;
  z-index             : 100;
  height              : 100vh;
  width               : 100vw;
  opacity             : 0.1;
  background          : #333;
  z-index             : 100;
  cursor              : move;
}
.window {
  position            : absolute;
  overflow            : hidden;
  margin-top          : 5px;
  margin-left         : 5px;
  min-width           : 10px;
  min-height          : 10px;
  background          : #988;
  padding             : 0;
}
.sizer {
  position            : relative;
  background          : #8a8;
  bottom              : 0;
  right               : 0;
  width               : 15px;
  height              : 15px;
  margin-top          : 120px;
  margin-left         : 250px;
  cursor              : move;
}
.wrap {
  position            : relative;
  background          : #565;
  width               : 100%;
  height              : 100%;
}
.content-outer {
  overflow            : hidden;
  top                 : 0;
  bottom              : 0;
  right               : 0;
  left                : 0;
  position            : absolute;
  background          : #a77;
  padding             : 0;
}
.corner {
  position            : sticky;
  width               : 25px;
  height              : 25px;
  top                 : 0;
  left                : 0;
  z-index             : 150;
  background          : red;
}
.top-line {
  top                 : 0;
  margin-top          : -25px;
  margin-left         : 25px;
  position            : sticky;
  height              : 25px;
  background          : pink;
  width               : 100%;
  display: table;
  white-space         : nowrap;
  z-index             : 100;
  overflow            : hidden;
}
.left-line {
  position            : sticky;
  max-height          : 100%;
  overflow            : hidden;
  background          : #494;
  width               : 25px;
  left                : 0;
  z-index             : 100;
  text-align          : center;
}
.left-line-c {
  height              : 5000px;
}
.content-inner {
  position            : absolute;
  overflow            : scroll;
  top                 : 25px;
  right               : 0;
  bottom              : 0;
  left                : 0;
}
.content-text {
  position            : absolute;
  top                 : 0;
  left                : 0;
  right               : 0;
  bottom              : 0;
  margin              : 25px ;
}
.content-spacer {
  background: rgb(186,124,13);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(186,124,13,1) 0%, rgba(112,25,58,0.9037815809917717) 53%, rgba(181,0,255,1) 100%);
  margin              : 15px;
  width               : 1000px;
  height              : 100px;
}
ul {
  list-style          : none;
  margin              : 0;
  padding             : 0;
}
.header {
  background          : #000;
  color               : #aaa;
  height              : 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="window">
        <div class="content-outer">
            <div class="header"><span>Header</span></div>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <div class="corner">C</div>
                <div class="top-line">
                  <div class="top-line-c"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="left-line">
                  <div class="left-line-c"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="content-text">
                  <div class="content-spacer">
                    <ul>
                      <li><label><input type="radio" name="sp" value="small">small</label></li>
                      <li><label><input type="radio" name="sp" value="wide" checked>wide</label></li>
                      <li><label><input type="radio" name="sp" value="high">high</label></li>
                      <li><label><input type="radio" name="sp" value="big">big</label></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sizer" id="sizer" tabindex="0"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just added `display: table;` on the `.top-line` class.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but no :). Problem then is that it expands beyond the content of the wrapper and makes the wrapper fit the sticky element, and not the content element. E.g. in the small example, it does not expand until 29-ish where the text ends, but expands until 33 - as in the whole width.

Comment: I added some more horisontal numbers + some vertical lines in the "small example" to make the effect more clear.